# Calling multiple leaflets of unique shapefiles and data frames on the same map in R

Tags: r, leaflet, heat-map, census, tmap

I am visualizing population heat maps for the commission districts of thirty Florida counties using Leaflet, but I can't figure out how to call them on the same leaflet map with the same population legend for all districts. I am starting with two counties for now, Alachua[1](https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/acgm::county-commissioner-districts/about) and Putnam[2](https://pc-open-data-site-pcgis.hub.arcgis.com/datasets/41f8ab0fab34423f99dbfd87e427a9ef_0/about); their commission districts shapefiles are linked at the bottom of this post. The closest method I have found is combineWidgets and this simply places the different leaflets for each county side by side, not on the same map. I also tried sync, but it doesn't work for this either. I tried to incorporate all county maps in one leaflet but I couldn't because the code to get the population for each county's commission districts is obviously extensive and highly unique. I also included a screenshot of what the two county districts look like side by side. I can make perfect tmaps of this data, but I want it to be interactive, on the same plane, so you can see all county commission districts for thirty counties colored by population percentile/tier.

**In R, I want to view multiple different shapefiles with different data frames on the same map but I cannot figure out how to call them in a single leaflet code or how to call them as individual leaflet maps overlayed on the same page.**

```
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(terra)
library(tidyverse)
library(spData)
library(tmap)
library(tidycensus)
library(raster)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.minicharts)
library(stringr)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(leafsync)
library(manipulateWidget)

census_api_key("***")
display.brewer.all()
pl_vars <- load_variables(2020, "pl", cache = TRUE)

#Alachua County - Intersection - Total Population of BCC Districts-----
download.file(url = "https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2020PL/STATE/12_FLORIDA/12001/tl_2020_12001_tabblock20.zip",
              destfile = "/Users/***/Documents/R Studio/Census Files/Block Files/Alachua/tl_2020_12001_tabblock20.zip", 
              mode = "wb")

unzip("/Users/***/Documents/R Studio/Census Files/Block Files/Alachua/tl_2020_12001_tabblock20.zip", exdir = "/Users/***/Documents/R Studio/Census Files/Block Files/Alachua/", overwrite = T)

alachua_blocks <- read_sf("/Users/***/Documents/R Studio/Census Files/Block Files/Alachua/tl_2020_12001_tabblock20.shp")

tm_shape(alachua_blocks) +
  tm_borders()

alachua_districts <- read_sf("/Users/***/Documents/R Studio/District Files/County Commission Districts/Alachua/Alachua_BCC/Commissioner_Districts.shp")

tm_shape(alachua_districts) +
  tm_borders()

pop_total_2020_alachua <- get_decennial(geography = "block",
                                state = "FL",
                                county = "Alachua",
                                variables = "P1_001N", 
                                year = 2020) %>%
  dplyr::select(GEOID, value) %>%
  rename(pop_total_2020_alachua = value)

alachua_blocks <- alachua_blocks %>%
  mutate(GEOID = GEOID20)

alachua_blocks <- inner_join(alachua_blocks, pop_total_2020_alachua, by = "GEOID")

tm_shape(alachua_blocks) +
  tm_polygons(col = "pop_total_2020_alachua")

alachua_districts_transform <- st_transform(alachua_districts, crs = crs(alachua_blocks))

alachua_districts_blocks <- st_intersection(x = alachua_blocks, y = alachua_districts_transform)

alachua_districts_blocks.df <- as.data.frame(alachua_districts_blocks)

district_pop_alachua.sf <- alachua_districts_blocks %>%
  group_by(COMMDIST) %>%
  summarize(district_pop_alachua = sum(pop_total_2020_alachua))

tm_shape(alachua_districts) +
  tm_borders() +
  tm_text(text = "COMMDIST")

view(district_pop_alachua.sf)

tm_shape(district_pop_alachua.sf) +
  tm_polygons(col = "district_pop_alachua", palette = "Blues") +
  tm_text(text = "COMMDIST")

Alachua_County_Total_Pop_Map = tm_shape(district_pop_alachua.sf) +
  tm_polygons(col = "district_pop_alachua", palette = "YlOrRd", title='',
              border.col='grey27', alpha=.9) +
  tm_layout(main.title = "Alachua", main.title.position = c('center', 'top'),
            legend.position = c("left", "bottom")) +
  tm_credits(text = "Total Population", position = c('center', 'bottom'),  fontface = "bold") +
  tm_text(text = "COMMDIST")

#Putnam County - Intersection - Total Population of BCC Districts-----
download.file(url = "https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2020PL/STATE/12_FLORIDA/12107/tl_2020_12107_tabblock20.zip",
              destfile = "/Users/***/Documents/R Studio/Census Files/Block Files/Putnam/tl_2020_12107_tabblock20.zip", 
              mode = "wb")

unzip("/Users/***/Documents/R Studio/Census Files/Block Files/Putnam/tl_2020_12107_tabblock20.zip", exdir = "/Users/***/Documents/R Studio/Census Files/Block Files/Putnam/", overwrite = T)

putnam_blocks <- read_sf("/Users/***/Documents/R Studio/Census Files/Block Files/Putnam/tl_2020_12107_tabblock20.shp")

tm_shape(putnam_blocks) +
  tm_borders()

putnam_districts <- read_sf("/Users/***/Documents/R Studio/District Files/County Commission Districts/Putnam/Putnam_BCC/County_Districts.shp")

tm_shape(putnam_districts) +
  tm_borders()

pop_total_2020_putnam <- get_decennial(geography = "block",
                                state = "FL",
                                county = "Putnam",
                                variables = "P1_001N", 
                                year = 2020) %>%
  dplyr::select(GEOID, value) %>%
  rename(pop_total_2020_putnam = value)

putnam_blocks <- putnam_blocks %>%
  mutate(GEOID = GEOID20)

putnam_blocks <- inner_join(putnam_blocks, pop_total_2020_putnam, by = "GEOID")

tm_shape(putnam_blocks) +
  tm_polygons(col = "pop_total_2020_putnam")

putnam_districts_transform <- st_transform(putnam_districts, crs = crs(putnam_blocks))

putnam_districts_blocks <- st_intersection(x = putnam_blocks, y = putnam_districts_transform)

putnam_districts_blocks.df <- as.data.frame(putnam_districts_blocks)

district_pop_putnam.sf <- putnam_districts_blocks %>%
  group_by(DISTRICTID) %>%
  summarize(district_pop_putnam = sum(pop_total_2020_putnam))

tm_shape(putnam_districts) +
  tm_borders() +
  tm_text(text = "DISTRICTID")

view(district_pop_putnam.sf)


tm_shape(district_pop_putnam.sf) +
  tm_polygons(col = "district_pop_putnam", palette = "Blues") +
  tm_text(text = "DISTRICTID")

Putnam_County_Total_Pop_Map = tm_shape(district_pop_putnam.sf) +
  tm_polygons(col = "district_pop_putnam", palette="YlOrRd", title='',
              border.col='grey27', alpha=.9) +
  tm_layout(main.title = "Putnam", main.title.position = c('center', 'top'),
            legend.position = c("left", "bottom")) +
  tm_credits(text = "Total Population", position = c('center', 'bottom'), fontface = "bold") +
  tm_text(text = "DISTRICTID")

#DISPLAY FUNCTION FOR ALL COUNTY MAPS-----
tmap_arrange(Alachua_County_Total_Pop_Map, Putnam_County_Total_Pop_Map)

#Alachua Leaflet Map Data
popupdistrictpopulationalachua <- paste(district_pop_alachua.sf$district_pop_alachua)
pal1 <- colorQuantile(palette = "YlOrRd", domain = district_pop_alachua.sf$district_pop_alachua, n = 7)

alachua_leaflet_total_pop <- district_pop_alachua.sf %>%
  st_transform(crs = "+init=epsg:4326") %>%
  leaflet(width = "100%") %>%
  addProviderTiles(provider = "CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  addPolygons(popup = ~ str_extract(COMMDIST, "^([^,]*)"),
              label = popupdistrictpopulationalachua,
              stroke = FALSE,
              smoothFactor = 0,
              fillOpacity = 0.7,
              color = ~ pal1(district_pop_alachua)) %>%
  addPolygons(data = FL_counties_transform, weight = 1, fill = FALSE, opacity = 1) %>%
  addLegend("bottomright", 
            pal = pal1,#colorQuantile(palette = "YlOrRd", domain = district_pop_alachua.sf$district_pop_alachua, n = 7), 
            values = ~ district_pop_alachua,
            title = "Alachua Population",
            opacity = 1)
alachua_leaflet_total_pop

#Putnam Leaflet Map Data
popupdistrictpopulationputnam <- paste(district_pop_putnam.sf$district_pop_putnam)
pal2 <- colorQuantile(palette = "YlOrRd", domain = district_pop_putnam.sf$district_pop_putnam, n = 5)

putnam_leaflet_total_pop <- district_pop_putnam.sf %>%
  st_transform(crs = "+init=epsg:4326") %>%
  leaflet(width = "100%") %>%
  addProviderTiles(provider = "CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  addPolygons(popup = ~ str_extract(DISTRICTID, "^([^,]*)"),
              label = popupdistrictpopulationputnam,
              stroke = FALSE,
              smoothFactor = 0,
              fillOpacity = 0.7,
              color = ~ pal2(district_pop_putnam)) %>%
  addLegend("bottomright", 
            pal = pal2,#colorQuantile(palette = "YlOrRd", domain = district_pop_putnam.sf$district_pop_putnam, n = 7), 
            values = ~ district_pop_putnam,
            title = "Putnam Population",
            opacity = 1)

#doesnt work
sync(alachua_leaflet_total_pop, putnam_leaflet_total_pop)

#Works, but only side by side
combineWidgets(alachua_leaflet_total_pop, putnam_leaflet_total_pop)
```

[image]

Comment: As of right now, your code is not reproducible. If you make your code reproducible by downloading files into a temporary directory (`tempdir()`), helping you fix this will be easier.

Comment: @geoscience123 Thank you for your comment. I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Copying the code I provided into R and downloading the shapefile data from the links I provided should allow anyone to run the entire script without issue.

Comment: Look at the beginning of your code. `destfile = "/Users/***/Documents/R Studio/Census Files/Block Files/Alachua/tl_2020_12001_tabblock20.zip"` refers to specific locations on your machine. When others run this code it will not be recognized by their machine.

Comment: Check out a recent question post of mine: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/443912/error-reading-layer-from-geodatabase-into-r. You'll see I use the `tempdir()` function to create a new directory to download files to. Feel free read more about this function elsewhere.

Comment: @geoscience123 I assumed others would know how to change file paths. The asterisks are just my user and census key blocked out. Thank you for your help, I will look into tempdir().

Comment: You're welcome. Look up the `reprex` package as well. It's a good tool to create reproducible examples so others can recreate your code. Also, `tempdir()` is useful because people may not want to permanently save large amounts of data to their machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't duplicate your legend format exactly, but in `{tmap}` you would simply map the two districts together by calling them with a `+` like this:

```
#toggle tmap interactive mode
tmap_mode("view")

 tm_shape(district_pop_putnam.sf) +
  tm_polygons(group="Putnam",
              col = "district_pop_putnam",
              palette="YlOrRd",
              style="quantile",
              title='Putnam Population',
              border.col='grey27',
              alpha=.9) +
  tm_text(text = "DISTRICTID")+
  
  tm_shape(district_pop_alachua.sf) +
  tm_polygons(group="Alachua Population",
              col = "district_pop_alachua",
              palette = "YlOrRd",
              style="quantile",
              title='Alachua Population',
              border.col='grey27',
              alpha=.9) +
   tm_text(text = "COMMDIST")
```

To produce the following:
[image: interactive tmap output]

`{tmap}` doesn't quite have the customizability of `{leaflet}` when it comes to titles and credits in view mode - is this why you opted to switch to `{leaflet}` or were you thinking it was your only option for displaying the districts together on the same interactive map?

Comment: Thank you, that's amazing! I was trying %>% instead of +. The interactive aspect is why I like leaflet, because you can see all counties simultaneously to compare and also zoom in to view one more closely, and I expect to have dozens of counties to display. However, I haven't been able to repeat what you did above using leaflet functions. I didn't know you could combine tmaps like that, but it's exactly what I needed. I found tmap_leaflet as an alternative, but it seems to be restricted to just tmap functions, so I can't use popups within addPolygons, for example. Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome. In my experience `{tmap}` is good for the interactivity features you're looking for (you just need to call `tmap_mode("view")` before calling your tmap - I added this as an edit to my original answer). This is because `{tmap}` leverages leaflet for its interactive functionality. Where I have been finding `tmap_leaflet()` handy for my own work has been for added customizability when it comes to using different basemaps, custom logos etc. to the interactive map.

Comment: That's very helpful to know, I appreciate it. I think I will do the same thing in using tmap_leaflet for my basemap and tmap for everything else.