# Error reading layer from geodatabase into R

Tags: r, file-geodatabase, sf

I am attempting to read a layer from a geodatabase into R. The error given is:

```
#> Error in CPL_get_z_range(obj, 2): z error - expecting three columns;
```

There is only one layer in the geodatabase. The geodatabase is available online, and a reprex is below:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.10.2, GDAL 3.4.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

tdir = tempdir()

roadurl = "https://gis.ny.gov/gisdata/fileserver/?DSID=1302&file=RoadwayInventorySystem.zip"
if(file.exists(paste(tdir,"/Roadway Inventory System 2020.gdb",sep=""))==F){
  download.file(roadurl,destfile = file.path(tdir,"Roads.zip"))
  unzip(file.path(tdir,"Roads.zip"),exdir=tdir)}

x <- st_read(dsn=paste(tdir,"/Roadway Inventory System 2020.gdb",sep=""),
              layer="Milepoint2020")
#> Reading layer `Milepoint2020' from data source 
#>   `/private/var/folders/24/9_h4zhq564g3zpvqp6jmbm0c0000gn/T/Rtmp0R3A1m/Roadway Inventory System 2020.gdb' 
#>   using driver `OpenFileGDB'
#> Error in CPL_get_z_range(obj, 2): z error - expecting three columns;
```

I'm not sure what the "three column error" is referring to. A similar error occurs when using `rgdal`.

Comment: Download keeps timing out after about 40Mb (of 111Mb)... That's not your problem though... Could it be put on a more reliable server or file sharing service?

Comment: Rats. I was hoping that wasn't going to be an issue. Do you know why an error like this might show up?

Comment: download.file in R failed five times at about 40Mb with a timeout error, `wget` on the command line got it all first time. Not sure if that's on my system config for download.file or what. Anyway, lets look...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like somewhere there's a coordinate with a broken XYZM point spec...

Converting to GeoPackage with -dim XYZM seems to fix this, creating a geopackage that reads into R okay:

```
ogr2ogr -dim XYZM -progress roadsXYZM.gpkg ./Roadway\ Inventory\ System\ 2020.gdb/
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

> roadXYZM = st_read("roadsXYZM.gpkg")
Reading layer `Milepoint2020' from data source 
  `/home/rowlings/Downloads/SO/Roads/roadsXYZM.gpkg' using driver `GPKG'
Simple feature collection with 387129 features and 127 fields
Geometry type: MULTILINESTRING
Dimension:     XYZM
Bounding box:  xmin: 105708.1 ymin: 4483306 xmax: 763916.1 ymax: 4985381
z_range:       zmin: 0 zmax: 0
m_range:       mmin: -1.083681e-06 mmax: 89.43588
Projected CRS: NAD83 / UTM zone 18N
```

Without the -dim XYZM option the resulting geopackage gives the same error as the gdb, so it looks like ogr2ogr is cleaning it up a bit when asked to have XYZM geometry. If you don't need Z or M use -dim XY to shrink the data a bit.

You can probably run `ogr2ogr` from the `gdalUtilities` package if you don't have the command line commands set up.

QGIS loads the GDB in fine without errors, so maybe it is more flexible to whatever is causing R to error.

Further inspection reveals the problem to be elements with EMPTY geometry, the first of which is row 249544. Here's an extract with GIS_ID and geometry columns:

```
249541 208940011 MULTILINESTRING ZM ((593502...
249542 208960011 MULTILINESTRING ZM ((594693...
249543 208917011 MULTILINESTRING ZM ((593771...
249544 208895011     MULTILINESTRING ZM (EMPTY)
249545 208881011 MULTILINESTRING ZM ((595392...
249546 209056011 MULTILINESTRING ZM ((599108...
249547 209026011 MULTILINESTRING ZM ((595819...
```

This may be a bug in `sf`, but at least its easy to replicate now without having to download something since I can probably create a small geopackage with an empty geometry object in it.

Comment: Per what @Jeffrey Evans noted below, the `ogr2ogr` method is the cleanest way to solve this. Accepting this answer. Unfortunately I'm having trouble with `gdal` in the terminal right now, so I have to use the ugly `sf` answer.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a z value associated with some of the features in the data, but not all as well as empty geometries, invalid geometry and perhaps duplicates. In other words, this data is an absolute mess. It sounds like ogr2ogr fixes much of this and is the easy way to go. However, if you must do this entirely in sf I can get you part way there.

To avoid the mismatch across geometries, you can read the data in as a GEOMETRYCOLLECTION then, drop the z value and cast back into a LINESTRING. We can drop the z value from the data and remove empty geometries but, there are some other issues with the data that I have not nailed down yet. This means that some of the standard sf ways (eg., `st_collection_extract`) to deal with this are failing.

First, let's read the data. Using the type=7 argument forces a GEOMETRYCOLLECTION. To drop the z value, we nest `st_read` in `st_zm`. The `st_geometry` call is to name the geometry column to "geometry"

```
library(sf)
dir = "C:/TMP/test"
d <- sf::st_zm(sf::st_read(file.path(dir, "Roadway Inventory System 2020.gdb"),
               layer="Milepoint2020", type=7), drop=TRUE, what="ZM")
  sf::st_geometry(d) <- "geometry"
```

Here is where things get weird. If we evaluate empty geometries, two observations (249544, 267927) are returned. However, when we coerce the data into a list we loose an additional observation, meaning that we are one row off from being able to relate back to the attributes.

```
# return indices of empty geometries 
which(st_is_empty(d))

# Return list of unique geometries representing 
# GEOMETRYCOLLECTION and sfg objects 
dg <- unique(st_geometry(d))

# Check number of observations between source data 
# and unique geometries (mismatch of three)  
length(dg)
nrow(d)
```

Now, there are numerous ways to do this but, we are going to iterate through the list of unique geometries, casting out of a GEOMETRYCOLLECTION object. This will result in a list of "LINESTRING, sfg" and now we can create an more standard standard sf object using `st_as_sf` and `st_sfc`. However, please note that due to the nature of the input data we end up with 387125 valid lines whereas the original data has 387129. As such, it is difficult (but not impossible) to relate the results back to the attribute table as there is now a 4 observation offset.

```
# Drop "GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY" observation (dg[-249542])       
( na.idx <- which(unlist(lapply(dg, st_is_empty))) )
  dg <- dg[-na.idx]

# Iterate through valid geometries to pull LINESTRING,
# coerce into sf object with no attributes 
dg <- lapply(dg, function(x) {
  suppressWarnings(st_cast(x, "LINESTRING"))
})
dg <- st_as_sf(st_sfc(dg))
  plot(dg)
```

Sorry, that all I have time for now but, at least it is a starting point.